# how to avoid infinite loop when using a constructor function to create an object

Tags: python, function, oop, methods, while-loop

```
# Import Modules
from Dice import dice
d10 = dice(10,1)
d4 = dice(4,1)

# Assign Classes
class Player_Character:
    def __init__(self, hp, maxhp, ac, THAC0, Surprise_Adjustment, Initiative_Adjustment):
        self.hp = int(hp)
        self.maxhp = int(maxhp)
        self.ac = int(ac)
        self.THAC0 = int(THAC0)
        self.Surprise_Adjustment = int(Surprise_Adjustment)
        self.Initiative_Adjustment = int(Initiative_Adjustment)

    def attack(self, goblin):
        Player_Character_Damage = d10.die_roll()
        goblin.hp -= Player_Character_Damage
        if (goblin.hp <= 0):
            print("congratulations you killed the goblin")

    def flee(self):
        print("you run away ")
        quit()

    def heal(self, Player_Character):
        Player_Character.hp += d10.die_roll()
        if Player_Character.hp >= Player_Character.maxhp:
            Player_Character.hp = Player_Character.maxhp

class goblin:
    def __init__(self, hp, maxhp, ac, THAC0, Surprise_Adjustment, Initiative_Adjustment):
        self.hp = int(hp)
        self.maxhp = int(maxhp)
        self.ac = int(ac)
        self.THAC0 = int(THAC0)
        self.Surprise_Adjustment = int(Surprise_Adjustment)
        self.Initiative_Adjustment = int(Initiative_Adjustment)

    def attack(self, Player_Character):
        goblin_damage = d4.die_roll()
        Player_Character.hp -= goblin_damage
        if (Player_Character.hp <= 0):
            print("oh dear you have died")
            del Player_Character


MrHezy = Player_Character(10, 20, 10, 15, 0, 2)

def spawn_goblin(goblin):
    G1 = goblin(5, 10, 8, 18, 0, 0)
    return G1

goblin1 = spawn_goblin(goblin)

def battle(goblin1):

    # user input
    player_initiative_adjustment = MrHezy.Initiative_Adjustment
    monster_initiative_adjustment = goblin1.Initiative_Adjustment

    #define while loop for the battle
    battle_not_over = 'yes'
    while battle_not_over == 'yes':

        #use random.randint(a,b) to generate player and monster base initiative
        player_base_initiative = d10.die_roll()
        monster_base_initiative = d10.die_roll()

        #subtract the adjustment to get player and monster initiative
        player_initiative = player_base_initiative - player_initiative_adjustment
        monster_initiative = monster_base_initiative - monster_initiative_adjustment

        #compare the initiatives and display the results
        if (player_initiative < monster_initiative):
            attack_flee_heal = input("congratulations you go first. Would you like to attack, flee, or heal?")
            while attack_flee_heal != 'attack' or 'flee' or 'heal':
                if attack_flee_heal == 'attack':
                    MrHezy.attack(goblin1)
                elif attack_flee_heal == 'heal':
                    MrHezy.heal(MrHezy)
                    print("the goblin attacks")
                    goblin1.attack(MrHezy)
                    break
                elif attack_flee_heal == 'flee':
                    MrHezy.flee()
                    break
        else:
            print("uhoh, the monsters go first, they attack!")
            goblin1.attack(MrHezy)
            attack_flee_heal = input("Would you like to attack, flee, or heal? ")
            while attack_flee_heal != 'attack' or 'flee' or 'heal':
                if attack_flee_heal == 'attack':
                    MrHezy.attack(goblin1)
                elif attack_flee_heal == 'heal':
                    MrHezy.heal(MrHezy)
                    print("the goblin attacks")
                    goblin1.attack(MrHezy)
                    break
                elif attack_flee_heal == 'flee':
                    MrHezy.flee()
                    break

#main game loop
while True:
    spawn_goblin(goblin)
    battle(goblin1)
```

This is a code for a battle simulator that ive been working on. it starts by importing a module that i made which consists of a class called 'dice' which I use for randomly generating numbers. Defining classes is next, with attributes including hp, maxhp, armor class, 'to hit armor class 0', surprise adjustment, and initiative adjustment, and methods including attack which allows you to attack the monsters, flee which exits the battle, and heal which gives your character more hit points. The program moves on to define the spawn_goblin() function which spawns a goblin (this works just fine for the first iteration of the loop). Then it moves on to the battle part which is pretty simple; all it does is check who goes first and then allows you to attack, or flee, or heal yourself. Please ignore the "heal" and "flee" methods, these are working just fine. The problem occurs when I attack the goblin. Instead of killing the goblin and spawning another it creates an infinite loop saying "congratulations you killed the goblin"

Comment: This code has been edited, it originally had a while loop that has been changed to an if statement. However the question still stands.

Comment: PS I think part of the problem may be that whenever you deal damage to the goblin it dies no matter how many hp it has or how much damage you do... How do I get the goblin to take only the damage that is dealt it?

Comment: PPS the reason that the goblin is dying every time is because instead of resetting the goblin's hp to 5 the program is continuously subtracting the hp into the negative numbers, so when the goblin respawns it has negative hp and it automatically says "congratulations you killed the goblin"... I still dont know how to fix this

Comment: Although the original question has been solved, the problem with the goblin hp remaining negative still stands (but without the infinite loop, now I can stop and heal in between attacks but every attack besides the first automatically kills the goblin because it has negative hp).

Comment: I solved the problem. I had to eliminate all the break statements from attack_flee_heal and add a        " if (goblin1.hp <= 0):
            print('oh dear looks like we need a new goblin')
            break" at the beginning of the while loop for the battle and "print("spawn another goblin")
    goblin1.hp = 0
    goblin1.hp += d10.die_roll()" to the bottom of the main game loop

Comment: I also had to delete every instance of 'while attack_flee_heal != 'attack' or 'flee' or 'heal':'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```py
> while (goblin.hp <= 0):
>            print("congratulations you killed the goblin")
> ```

I think this part of your code is wrong. The `while` should be `if`, since you only want to *check* if the goblin has died, and run some code **once**. Once the goblin's HP becomes lesser than or equal to `0`, the `print` statement will loop forever since the expression `goblin.hp <= 0` will always return `True`.

**EDIT**: Now where I think your code is wrong is here:

> ```py
> while attack_flee_heal != 'attack' or 'flee' or 'heal':
>                if attack_flee_heal == 'attack':
>                    MrHezy.attack(goblin1)
>                elif attack_flee_heal == 'heal':
>                    MrHezy.heal(MrHezy)
>                     ...
> ```

I think you have missed the `break` in the first `if` (`if attack_flee_heal == 'attack'`
Also, it would be more appropriate to use an `if` here rather than a `while`, since, as I mentioned above, you only want to check **once**.

Comment: It makes no difference, the original code I used used an if statement, I changed it to a while loop so I could use 'break' which didnt work

Comment: Why do you want to use `break`?

Comment: to break the while loop and continue on to the rest of the code

Comment: If you use an `if`, the `print` will only run once. The `while` causes the `print` to recurse.

Comment: Try running the code, in this case the infinite loop remains

Comment: you are absolutely right, without the break statement that would create an infinite loop, but there is something else creating an infinite loop as well

Comment: @HezekiaBodine I have edited my question, can you see whether it is working now?

Comment: I would also remark on `attack_flee_heal != 'attack' or 'flee' or 'heal'` which is always true. And should be written as `attack_flee_heal not in ('attack', 'flee', 'heal')`.

Comment: Adding a break statement to the attack section of attack_flee_heal broke the infinite loop.

Comment: Dan D. when I did that the attack method no longer worked